# create one General method to switch between Multiple Screens

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have three screen, named : ViewController , SecondViewController, ThirdViewController

two buttons in each screen
in ViewController       : gotoSecondViewController , gotoThirdViewController
in SecondViewController : gotoViewController       , gotoThirdViewController
in ThirdViewController  : gotoViewController       , gotoSecondViewController

i need to create one general method which can be called from above six methods which are associated with six buttons to switch between three views

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  MultiCommonMethod
//
//  Created by Hitendra C-Lover on 12/23/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Hitendra C-Lover. All rights reserved.
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end


//
//  ViewController.m
//  MultiCommonMethod
//
//  Created by Hitendra C-Lover on 12/23/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Hitendra C-Lover. All rights reserved.
//
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)gotoSecondView:(id)sender {

    SecondViewController *screen2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:screen2 animated:YES completion:NO];
    [GlobleMethods changeScreen:@"SecondViewController"];
}

- (IBAction)gotoThirdView:(id)sender {

    ThirdViewController *screen3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:screen3 animated:YES completion:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end

****************************
//
//  SecondViewController.h
//  MultiCommonMethod
//
//  Created by Hitendra C-Lover on 12/23/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Hitendra C-Lover. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@end


//
//  SecondViewController.m
//  MultiCommonMethod
//
//  Created by Hitendra C-Lover on 12/23/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Hitendra C-Lover. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SecondViewController.h"


@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (IBAction)gotoFirstView:(id)sender {

    ViewController *screen1 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:screen1 animated:YES completion:NO];
}

- (IBAction)gotoThirdView:(id)sender {

    ThirdViewController *screen3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:screen3 animated:YES completion:NO];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end

*****************

//
//  ThirdViewController.h
//  MultiCommonMethod
//
//  Created by Hitendra C-Lover on 12/23/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Hitendra C-Lover. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "GlobleMethods.h"

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController

@end


//
//  ThirdViewController.m
//  MultiCommonMethod
//
//  Created by Hitendra C-Lover on 12/23/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Hitendra C-Lover. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface ThirdViewController ()

@end

@implementation ThirdViewController

- (IBAction)gotoFirstView:(id)sender {

    ViewController *screen1 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:screen1 animated:YES completion:NO];
}

- (IBAction)gotoSecondView:(id)sender {

    SecondViewController *screen2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:screen2 animated:YES completion:NO];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create method which returns UIViewController and by pass screen number the method can return right view controller and after that you can present it in view hierarchy. For example

```
-(UIViewController*)getViewControllerByNumber:(NSUInteger)screenNo
{
    if (screenNo = 2)
    {
        retuen [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else if (screenNo = 3)
    {
        return [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
}
```

And you can call it like that:

```
 - (IBAction)gotoThirdView:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *viewc= [self getViewControllerByNumber:3];
    // Or you can create class method and call it like that:
    // UIViewController *viewc= [ViewManager getViewControllerByNumber:3];
    [self presentViewController:viewc animated:YES completion:NO];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (IBAction)gotoView:(id)sender{
   [GlobleMethods gotoView:sender deleget:self];
}

bind above method to any button's touchUpInside,
buttone title must be screen no like, 1,2,3


//
//  GlobleMethods.h
//  MultiCommonMethod
//
//  Created by Hitendra C-Lover on 12/23/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Hitendra C-Lover. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobleMethods : NSObject

+(UIViewController*)getViewControllerByNumber:(NSUInteger)screenNo;
+ (void) gotoView:(id)sender deleget:(id)deleget;

@end

****************************************************

//
//  GlobleMethods.m
//  MultiCommonMethod
//
//  Created by Hitendra C-Lover on 12/23/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Hitendra C-Lover. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GlobleMethods.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@implementation GlobleMethods

+(UIViewController*)getViewControllerByNumber:(NSUInteger)screenNo
{
    if (screenNo == 2)
    {
        return [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else if (screenNo == 3)
    {
        return [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
}

+ (void)gotoView:(id)sender deleget:(id)deleget{
    int screenNo = [[sender currentTitle]intValue];
    UIViewController *viewc= [self getViewControllerByNumber:screenNo];
    [deleget presentViewController:viewc animated:YES completion:NO];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why did you copy code from the previous answer and answered your own question?